# Magento Facebook Login (belvg) stoped working

Tags: magento-1, login, facebook

We are using the belvg "Facebook Connect and Like" module on magento1 and noticed that login functionality is not working anymore. The error thrown at frontend is:

```
 Facebook Connect attempt failed
```

In the log files we can see this error.

```
2017-06-02T17:24:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): Access Token not found
```

PS. I did find the solution, so i made this post just to help others..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that FB login has stop working is that Facebook had stop supporting API v2.2 after **25/03/2017** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

The v2.3 includes a change to the format of access tokens that now is formated as JSON instead of URL encoded.

> [Oauth Access Token] Format - The response format of
>   https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token returned when you
>   exchange a code for an access_token now return valid JSON instead of
>   being URL encoded. The new format of this response is {"access_token":
>   {TOKEN}, "token_type":{TYPE}, "expires_in":{TIME}}. We made this
>   update to be compliant with section 5.1 of RFC 6749.

In order to make it compatible with the new format you must edit file

```
app/code/community/Belvg/FacebookFree/Model/Request.php
```

and arround line 49 change

```
 if (isset($signed_request['access_token'])) {
    return $signed_request['access_token'];
 }
```

to

```
 if (isset(json_decode($token_response)->access_token)) {
     return json_decode($token_response)->access_token;
 }
```

Note: Keep in mind that in order for this module to work, you must rename folder
**BelVG** to **Belvg** inside app/code/community

Answer (score 0):

@karpa you can get the updated version of the module at our [store](https://store.belvg.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=facebook).

This fix was applied on February.

```
$token_response = $this->getFbData($url);
$signed_request = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($token_response, true);
if (isset($signed_request['access_token'])) {
    return $signed_request['access_token'];
}
```

Comment: Good to hear! I have downloaded the version from magento connect. So i guess it is best to upload the new version there or make a big note that the version on magento connect is obsolete. Thanks